# Is there a standard public-friendly keyset available for vim?

Tags: windows, macos, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I've seen several bits of documentation on how to do ad-hoc vim key bindings.

Since I'm trying to pitch vim (or, to be more accurate, the idea of free 'nix text editors in general) to a coworker, I'm hoping to make it as painless for them as possible.

**In contract to that ad-hoc approach, is there a wholesale block of widely accepted text I can throw into a *.vimrc* file in order to make most "standard" mac or windows keyboard shortcuts behave roughly the way they would on those systems?** (For example, ctrl-s for save, ctrl-f to bring up a search, ctrl-v to "put" a string, ctrl-w to close, ctrl-q to quit, or some subset/superset of those ...)

Thanks for any help. I'm happy to build these on my own if needed, but I figured that if I'm documenting it for future use, I might as well link out instead of rebuilding the wheel.

I did a bit of looking around before asking, but if this is a duplicate, feel free to merge.

Comment: I would just show them how powerful vim could be (think about what you want to show first), then give them the pure vim. tell them to config their own vim. mapping `c-s c-f, c-c, c-v` to those functions are (IMO) bad idea. They have to learn anyway. Riding horse and driving car are different, want to drive? learn it. that's it.

Comment: That really against what vim is. Put them through the `vimtutor` tutorial, and tell them if they find they're hitting the same key/combo more than a few times in a row they should ask you (and/or look up) the right way to do it.

Comment: I understand that argument, and it goes well with my personal approach to learning. But different people have different learning styles, per this piece. 

http://bit.ly/1jxVrTJ

(I don't know the author, but he seems reasonably intelligent, as does my coworker. They both have simply expressed skepticism about the idea of learning a language and an environment at the same time, rather than adding pieces at their leisure -- a sentiment that I understand as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mswin.vim` provides many typical Windows keybindings, so that any *Notepad* user will feel almost comfortable with Vim. You enable that by putting

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
```

into your `~/.vimrc`, cp. `:help mswin.vim`.

```
:set insertmode
```

(or starting via `evim`) almost turns Vim into *Notepad* by defaulting to insert mode :-)

The downside is similar to training wheels for bikes: It allows for some quick successes, but overall takes longer to become proficient. (I personally started out with mswin.vim, and gradually reduced the mappings.)

Comment: Thanks. This looks just about perfect. (And I agree about the training wheels -- I'd personally rather dive right in.)

Answer (score 1):

There is cream. It's a vim plugin that starts in insert mode and rebinds ctrl-c to copy, ctrl-v to paste etc...

http://cream.sourceforge.net/home.html

It's intended to make things easier for people used to editing in more conventional editors. That said I never used it. I learned vim the hard way and don't regret it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely check it out.